# Full-Calendar - JSP/Servlet Integration

Tags: java, jsp, fullcalendar

I have searched a lot on Google that how Full Calendar can be implemented with JSP/Servlet. People are giving an idea- but no one have shared working code.
Just wondering if someone have really implemented in JSP/Servlet then I would request to share the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use javascript implementation of Calendar control. There are a lot of implementation and integration is easy. For example, [jquery full calendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). Just add javascript to you jsp.